# How to insert all values from another table using sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

//table main_lookup

```
const main_lookup=DB.connection.define('main_lookup',{

main_lookup_name: {
    type :Sequelize.STRING,
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
},

value:{
type:Sequelize.JSON,
allowNull:false,
}

});
```

//table 2

```
const school_lookup= DB.connection.define('school_lookup',{


school_id : {
    type :Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    references: {            
         model: schools,
         key: 'school_id'
    }
},  
lookup_name: {
    type :Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true,
    allowNull: false
},
value: {
type: Sequelize.JSON,
allowNull: false,
}


});
```

i need to send data from main_lookup table to school lookup data

```
school_id // that is given by me 
lookup_name // that is copy from main_lookup
value // that is copy from main_look_up
```

example
    main lookup // table1

```
main_lookup_name value
---------------- -----
language         ['english','tamil']
subject          ['social','maths']
```

the solution is similar to the content following this

```
school_lookup // table2 //needed 

school_id lookup    value
--------- ------    -----
cit       language  ['english','tamil']
cit       subject   ['social','maths']
```

i need help in sequelize with simple ways

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using sequelize like how people use microsoft excel or microsoft access. You can simply make relation in sequelize.
here is the code

//school-model

```
    const School=Sequelize.define('school',{

        name: {
            type :Sequelize.STRING,
            allowNull: false
        }
    });
```

//subject

```
    const Subject= Sequelize.define('subject',{

        type: {
            type :Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        value: {
            type: Sequelize.ARRAY,
            allowNull: false,
        }
    });
```

//database

```
    const School = require('./path_to_schoolmodel');
    const Subject = require('./path_to_subjectmodel');

    Subject.belongsTo(School);
    School.hasMany(Subject);
```

School model

```
    id name
    -- ---------------------
    1  'fullstack academy'
    2  'app academy'

    Subject model
    id type      value                schoolID
    -- --------- -------------------- ------------------
    1  language  ['english','tamil']  2
    2  subject   ['social','maths']   1
```

if you setup model relationship you should be able to see you data like this.

Then when you use Sequelize model querying on your server side.

```
    const School = require('./path_to_schoolmodel');
    const Subject = require('./path_to_subjectmodel');
    School.findAll({
         include:[ Subject ]
       })
       .then(console.log)
       .catch(console.error)
```

your console.log should return something like

```
    [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'fullstack academy'
            subjects: [{
                id: 2,
                type: 'subject',
                value: [
                   'socials', 'maths'
                ]
            }]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'app academy'
            subjects: [{
                id: 1,
                type: 'language',
                value: [
                   'english', 'tamil'
                ]
            }]
        },
    ]
```

Comment: thank you for your response . but i need to transfer data one table to another table .you had given select query operation

Comment: i need to something like INSERT INTO TABLE2 (COL1, COL2, COL3) SELECT COL1, COL4, COL7 FROM TABLE1 in sequalize

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw query to do the same.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

sequelize.query("insert into <table1> select * from <table2>", { 
    type:Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
}).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results) // or do whatever you want
})
```